# how scale dependent props in react with typescript?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, types

The problem is based on the dependency of properties, where I have a property that depends on another property, but without both the component should continue to work.

In the code example below I have a component that has the inviteLabel prop and the onClickInvite prop. These properties are not required, but if I add one, I must add the other.

so does contactLabel and onClickContact.

```
import React from "react";

type Props = {
  fullName: string;
  onClickInvite?: () => void;
  inviteLabel?: string;
  onClickContact?: () => void;
  contactLabel?: string;
};

const CardWithUserDetails = (props: Props) => {
  return <div>test</div>;
};

function DebugWhileDeveloping() {
  return <CardWithUserDetails fullName="test name" />;
}
```

How can I create a type that can make this dependency work? and how to scale the solution if you have to add more properties?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a type guard to check for the conditional existence of required properties:

```
type Props = {
  fullName: string;
  onClickInvite?: () => void;
  inviteLabel?: string;
  onClickContact?: () => void;
  contactLabel?: string;
};

function hasInviteLabel(props: Props): props is Required<Props> {
  return !!props.inviteLabel;
}

function hasContactLabel(props: Props): props is Required<Props> {
  return !!props.contactLabel;
}

const CardWithUserDetails = (props: Props) => {
  if (hasInviteLabel(props) && !props.onClickInvite) {
    throw new Error("You must provide an onClickInvite prop if you provide an inviteLabel prop");
  }
  if (hasContactLabel(props) && !props.onClickContact) {
    throw new Error("You must provide an onClickContact prop if you provide a contactLabel prop");
  }

  return <div>test</div>;
};

function DebugWhileDeveloping() {
  return <CardWithUserDetails fullName="test name" />;
}
```

This type guard ensures that both props are present when either one is provided, and throws an error if a prop is missing. This approach can be scaled to any number of props.